# Error en brackets por de extension GITHUB error Failed to connect nodeJS

Tags: brackets

Quise comenzar a practicar con repositorios de github, a lo que me puse manos a la obra y concluí subiendo un archivo de hola mundo y lo subí, hasta ahí genial todo.

El problema viene cuando reabro `brackets` y me da el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aparte, de editarme media pregunta te agredeceria que respondieras tambien a la misma, si no simplemente sigue mirando preguntasmas abajo, gracias. Los actos de correccion también suelen venir acompañados de alguna respuesta coherente y de paso se deja la respuesta depurada para proximas personas vayan a entrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me lo solucioné, si te sale el pantallazo descrito en el editor brackets, simplemente descargate el nodejs de us pagina oficial y se solucionara el error.